# Relating Wordpress posts to a particular time of the year

Tags: mysql, wordpress, function, date, post

I have a 'diary' type blog in which I want to highlight all the posts made around the current day and month, regardless of the year. You could say they need to be 'seasonal'.

Changing the order to **day of the year**, starting with TODAY seems a good way of achieving this. In MySQL a conditional ORDER BY is required so that dates before NOW(), less a few days, are sorted to the end of the list.

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN DAYOFYEAR(post_date) < DAYOFYEAR(NOW())-14 THEN 1
    ELSE 0  END ASC, DAYOFYEAR(post_date) asc
```

Tested independently of Wordpress this gives the desired sort order eg:

```
post_date
2022-04-21 12:53:35 
2022-04-29 20:17:35 (today's date)
2019-04-30 13:35:12 
2018-05-23 10:10:12
2017-07-11 13:06:35
2021-09-03 08:11:08
2017-01-01 20:17:35
2021-03-22 12:19:11
2020-04-03 11:12:44
```

A function like the one below can be used to change sort order of the Wordpress query but it's not working. Is **pre_get_posts** really the place to do this and am I incorporating the ORDER BY statement in the correct way? Could my theme (Elegant Themes 'Extra') be interfering with the sort order?

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'sort_posts_by_day_of_year');
            
function sort_posts_by_day_of_year($query) {
//gets the global query var object

global $wp_query;
            
//gets the front page id set in options
$front_page_id = get_option('page_on_front');
            
if ( 'page' != get_option('show_on_front') || $front_page_id != $wp_query->query_vars['page_id'] )
                    return;

if ( !$query->is_main_query() )
                return;

$query-> set('post_type' ,'post');
                
$query-> set('post__in' ,array( $front_page_id));
    $query-> set('orderby' ,'CASE 
    WHEN DAYOFYEAR(post_date) < DAYOFYEAR(NOW())-14 THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 END ASC, DAYOFYEAR(post_date) asc');
                
$query->set( 'order' , 'ASC' );
            
//we remove the actions hooked on the '__after_loop' (post navigation)
remove_all_actions ( '__after_loop');
}
```

The above doesn't have any effect even after removing surplus line returns (the sort order remains as standard) but it doesn't cause a crash. Is the syntax correct but the function is not working in the right place? I tried changing $front_page_id to the actual page number but that had no effect.

Any help/advice very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

An answer to my own question - I have corrected the MySQL part so that it works - just a simple error of logic was causing the problem. I also added in -14 to make the posts for NOW() start appearing two weeks earlier:

```
SELECT post_TYPE, post_date,ID,post_title,DAYOFYEAR(post_date) from wp_posts where post_type = 'post' 
ORDER BY CASE  
WHEN DAYOFYEAR(post_date) < DAYOFYEAR(NOW())-14 THEN 1
       ELSE 0
      END ASC, DAYOFYEAR(post_date) asc
```

And thanks to Wordpress.org Forums I have been able to fix the rest of my problem.

> The orderby query var only accepts certain pre-defined values. You
> cannot pass arbitrary columns or SQL this way. You can use the
> "posts_orderby" filter to get WP to use any SQL order clause you'd
> like. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_orderby/

My current solution is:

```
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'seasonal_posts_orderby');
function seasonal_posts_orderby($sortorder) {
    $sortorder = "CASE WHEN DAYOFYEAR(post_date) < DAYOFYEAR(NOW())-14 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END , DAYOFYEAR(post_date) ";
    return $sortorder;   
}
```

This affects all queries including the dashboard list of posts - which suits me well at present, but I may need to add a posts filter to avoid sorting projects, which I am thinking of using.